# A polynomial in $g$ approximates every $f$ iff $g$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, approximation-theory

> Prove or disprove the following statement:
>
> There exists a continuous function $g$ defined on $[a,b]$ with $g(x)\neq x $ for at least one $x\in[a,b]$ such that for every continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$, given any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist constants $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ depending only on $g,f,\varepsilon$ such that $$|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^na_k(g(x))^k|<\varepsilon$$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ **IF AND ONLY IF** $g$ is injective.

After zhw's comment, the simpler version of this question stands as:

> Prove or disprove that if $g$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ then polynomials in $g$ are dense in $C[a,b]$ iff $g$ is injective.

I think that the statement is true. I attempted to prove it as follows:

> First the **IF** part. If $g$ is given to be injective, then I let $g(x)=\dfrac{x}{2}$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then $g(x)\neq x$ for at least one $x\in[a,b]$ but I can use a polynomial in $g$ to approximate any continuous function on $[a,b]$ since I will basically be using a polynomial of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{a_k}{2^k}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k$ where $b_k$ will be obtained from the approximating polynomials of Weierstrass Approximation Theorem and hence I will get $a_k=2^kb_k$ which depend only on $f,\varepsilon$ as $b_k$ depend only on $f,\varepsilon$. Dependency on $g$ is removed as we have boiled down to a polynomial only.
>
> Now the **ONLY IF** part. Suppose $g$ is not injective, then there exist $x_1\neq x_2\in[a,b]$ such that $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$. Now suppose this $g$ satisfies all the conditions mentioned, then we can write, for every continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$, given any $\varepsilon>0$, that there exist constants $a_0,a_1,...,a_k$ depending only on $f,g,\varepsilon$ such that $$|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^na_k(g(x))^k|<\varepsilon$$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. In particular, take $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$ which will give,$$|f(x_1)-\sum_{k=0}^na_k(g(x_1))^k|<\varepsilon$$  and $$|f(x_2)-\sum_{k=0}^na_k(g(x_2))^k|<\varepsilon$$
> Now, $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)=|f(x_1)-\sum_{k=0}^na_kg(x_1)^k+\sum_{k=0}^na_kg(x)^k-f(x_2)|$$$$\leq|f(x_1)-\sum_{k=0}^na_kg(x_1)^k|+|\sum_{k=0}^na_kg(x)^k-f(x_2)|<2\varepsilon$$
> This implies that every continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ must have $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ but this is not true as in particular, taking $f(x)=x$ which is bijective contradicts this. Hence $g$ must be injective.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You can't "let $g(x)=x/2$." You need to prove it for all injective $g$.

Comment: Is your question whether a $g(x)$ exists (your beginning "There exists ... $g$"), or whether any injective $g(x)$ will do the job - you end "if and only if $g$ is injective"? Are you intending to ask whether the $a_i$ exist for all injective $g$? At the moment your statement to be proved is logically confused.

Comment: Your statement is nonsensical, you cannot say "there exists $g$ such that for all functions $f$, something is true if $g$ is injective". Either $g$ is quantified in the beginning ("there exists $g$)" or not, you cannot have both.

Comment: I don't think this holds for every injective $g$? I guess the question is asking to prove whether there exists a function $g$ which approximates $f$ in this way, and then to show that if such a $g$ exists, then it must be injective.

Comment: Why not? Seems like this will hold: If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ then polynomials in $g$ are dense in $C([a,b])$ iff $g$ is injective.

Comment: Okay, zhw feel free to edit please, if you think your statement and the question statement are same. I have not studied density properties now. But, one thing is, does your statement retain all the conditions in my statement? Please check. If so, then kindly edit.

Comment: Then I am editing the question zhw. My previous comment was aimed at your unedited comment.

Comment: BTW zhw can you prove that this holds for every continuous injective $g$? Please show me how to prove it because it is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous injective function $g$ on $[a,b]$ maps $[a,b]$ bijectively onto some $[c,d],$ and its inverse $g^{-1}$ has the same property going backwards. Let $f\in C([a,b]).$ Then $f\circ g^{-1}\in C([c,d]).$ Hence there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n\to f\circ g^{-1}$ uniformly on $[c,d].$ This implies $p_n\circ g \to (f\circ g^{-1})\circ g = f$ uniformly on $[a,b].$

Comment: This is a nice answer, except that I do not really get why $p_n\circ g\to(f\circ g^{-1})\circ g$ i.e. why will composition of functions also be uniformly convergent?

Comment: Think about it. You'll smile when you figure it out.

Comment: So you took $g(x)=y$ for $x\in[a,b]$ and then used uniform convergence of $P_n(y)$ to $(f\circ g^{-1})(y)$. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Principles of Mathematical Analysis (W. Rudin) and read Stone's-Weirstrass Theorem Concerning algebras that separate points and their densities in C[a,b] then the result you are proving is a consequence of that: Just take the smallest algebra containing g.

Comment: Actually I have no knowledge about algebras and separation theorems. Could you kindly give a proof supposing $g$ is injective? As you can see, I already proved the ONLY IF part.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) applies here: the algebra generated by $g$ is dense in $C([a,b])$ if and only if it separates points, and this is true if and only if $g$ is injective.